# Browser issue while processing 6K Records

Tags: php, mysql, browser

I have an issue. I am accessing a Data Migration application where i am transferring 6K records from a CSV file to Mysql database using PHP. The server(Ubuntu) is at different location. what i am noticing is that in my local host environment it is working fine.(There are 3 different scripts for validations,insertion and update) but when i am uploading the same file from Mozilla browser using server application the first script executed for two times and then after that it is showing "The connection was reset" but when i used Chrome browser it worked fine.Initially i analyzed the reason that it is not able to return any value to browser within certain interval of time and that's why the browser would have sent another request and for that i put blank echo statements in between the script but even though it is not working in Mozilla Firefox. i am using recent version of Firefox. One more thing i would like to add in back end it is database query is executing executing. i have used set time limit and ignore user abort. Please Help...

Comment: How are you inserting the values? It's possible that the connection got reset because you pushed in more than the DB could process at once. Are you batching the inserts or doing them one at a time?

Comment: You haven't stated how you're doing the CSV->MySQL import, but I regularly do 60,000+ record imports using MySQL's `LOAD DATA INFILE` command. If you're doing it using a loop in PHP then you're doing it wrong (and it will definitely be slow).

Comment: ethrbunny i am inserting the records records by records not at a time. But It is working fine with Chrome Browser. The issue is with Mozilla Firefox only.

Comment: No i am not inserting using Load Data infile because i need to do many validations regarding header names, replacing foreign characters with ascii value and after that i am inserting into mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for replying late, i found a solution long back.I am calling the next page(which i need to execute) using system call and at the same time referring the current page to home page and through this way actual processing is happening in the back end and it is not creating any problem related to browser request. In earlier case i was simply executing complex mysql codes through php and browser was not getting any output that's why it was firing multiple request after some point of time.